# Not a DRM File, opening notmally

Tags: android, imageview, android-view, android-bitmap

I am looking for a solution regarding a repeating log print that is caused by calling
`BitmapFactory.decodeFile`.

In My app I have a `ListView` that is being redrawn by a timer every second.
The `ListView` has an `ImageView` that gets is image source from the local storage, (not from the network)

The image is stored in:

```
filePath = /data/data/com.xxx.testlib/files/b22a1a294fd6e5ad3ea3d25b63c4c735.jpg
```

I am using the following code to redraw the image and it is working fine. with out exception.

```
try
{
 File filePath = context.getFileStreamPath(imageName);

 if(filePath.exists()){

    bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath.getPath());

 }

}catch (Exception e) 
{

 e.printStackTrace();

}
```

But when preforming the following line:

```
bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath.getPath());
```

I get a print in the log as follow:

```
03-07 09:55:29.100: I/System.out(32663): Not a DRM File, opening notmally
03-07 09:55:29.105: I/System.out(32663): buffer returned 
....
```

How can I get read from the printing to the log?

Also it lags the phone whenever this operation is performed. And this reduced performance is noticeable specially when the phone is `Waked up` and we return to activity with this code.

Its more than a year for OP and still no answer is found. If anyone has found solution then please post it.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, bitmap is successfully returned but every time it executes `BitmapFactory.DecodeFile` it prints this message in the console. Have you found anything to solve the issue yet?

Comment: And what is the issue? It works, it just logs info to the log. That's what log is for...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24946923/

Answer (score -1):

I also got the same exception when I tried to save the image captured by camera directly to: `/data/data/com.xxx.testlib/images/b22a1a294fd6e5ad3ea3d25b63c4c735.jpg`.

Then I first saved the image to default location used by camera and the copied it to: `/data/data/com.xxx.testlib/images/b22a1a294fd6e5ad3ea3d25b63c4c735.jpg`.

and now "Not a DRM File, opening notmally" is removed from the log and saved the image successfully.

Conclusion: folder :- `/data/data/com.xxx.testlib/` is private and can be accessible from inside the application only.

Comment: this not the solution in any way, as this problem is not pertinent only while reading/writing file from sdcard. This problem occurs whenever we use `BitmapFactory`!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's a permission error.
Do you have added the right permission in your Manifest ?

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`