# Android - What does the message: "Not a DRM File, opening Normally" from the LogCat mean?

Tags: android

I'm fairly new to Android and I have been working from the past couple of days with images that I save to internal storage and then assign it to different elements (just for testing), like a button (with setBackground) or to an ImageView. In every single instance this message of not a DRM File appears on the LogCat.

I've been trying to find what this means, but with no luck. I'd really appreciate if anyone could shed some light into this subject.

PS: This is my first post in this forum so I apologize in advance if I'm making any mistakes or omissions while forming this question. Thanks for the understanding!

UPDATE: Just to add some results I got yesterday from testing, apparently generating Drawables from images in internal storage make this type of message appear and Android is unable to decode said images, however if those images are moved to external storage then they can be converted to Drawables and work without problems. Hope this can help anyone else stuck in this kind of situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DRM stands for Digital Rights Management.  It's normally a special keys used by owners of content to make sure that your device is authorized to view/play the content.  iTunes was notorious for this for ages.

All it's doing is letting you know that the material you are opening is not DRM protected, and therefore can be opened normally.

Comment: Thanks, I thought the same, but when I use one image that I want to display on an image view, it only shows the DRM message when that image is used from internal storage, when I used from external storage no message appears (and the image displays correctly).

Comment: If its external there is no way DRM would apply.  It's not on the device.  Makes sense, doesn't it?